# How to set the last point's position in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Is there a way put the last point of a series at charts' center or set some right-margin in Highcharts **StockChart**

like this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [`xAxis.maxPadding`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.maxPadding)?

I created this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4K9B2/) to show the result.

**EDIT**

OK you use StockChart. In that case you need to set [`ordinal`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.ordinal) to `false`:

```
    xAxis: {
        maxPadding: 1,
        ordinal: false
    },
```

Please check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bBL82/).

Comment: @PaulYin Are you referring to `highstock`? How about [this](http://jsfiddle.net/bBL82/)?

Comment: maxPadding doesnt work in the highstock, when you click on the any button in rangeselector. In other cases works properly.

Comment: @SebastianBochan Yes and it seems by-design. The doc said the option will be ignored when `setExtremes` is called.